# how to pass array argument or parameter from template in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive customValidationVariance for validation input fields.

I want to pass `wdaServiceModel.to3` , `wdaServiceModel.to2` arguments as a array or object but I am unable to pass it..

I tried :

```
custom-validation-variance="{{wdaServiceModel.to3}} {{wdaServiceModel.to2}} "
```

I am checking the attr value in my directive like this :

```
var comparisonModel = $attrs.customValidationVariance;
```

Comment: You can use `$scope` for passing complex object, A good read http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
custom-validation-variance="{{[wdaServiceModel.to3,wdaServiceModel.to2]}} "
```

Comment: It creates string array of interger values.. I am unable to convert in array integers..